# Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis Chapter 5 Exercise 15

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to solve it using generalized mean value theorem (Theorem 5.9 in the book), but ran into a wrong conclusion.

Let $f$ be twice-differentiable real function on $(a, \infty)$. Let $M_{0}, M_{1}, M_{2}$ be the least upper bounds of $|f(x)|, |f'(x)|, |f''(x)|$, respectively, on $(a, \infty)$. Prove that $$M_{1}^{2} \leq 4M_{2}M_{0}$$

Fix $y\in (a,\infty)$. Then for any $z\in(a,\infty)$ where $y<z$, for some $t\in(y,z)$,

$$[f(z)-f(y)]f'(t)=[f'(z)-f'(y)]f(t)$$

Since $y\neq z$,

$$\frac{[f(z)-f(y)]f'(t)}{z-y}=\frac{[f'(z)-f'(y)]f(t)}{z-y}$$

If I take the limit as $z$ goes to $y$, then it becomes:

$$[f'(y)]^{2}=f''(y)f(y)$$

which implies:

$$[f'(y)]^{2} \leq M_{2}M_{0}$$ and therefore

$$M_{1}^{2} \leq M_{2}M_{0}$$

But clearly, this is wrong from the hint in the book since $M_{1}^{2}= 4M_{2}M_{0}$ can actually happen. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Could you point to where the error occurred?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to show?

Comment: thank you for the comment! but the book shows that equality can occur, but that means the conclusion I have arrived at would be wrong. Also wouldn't f'(t) and f(t) go to f'(y) and f(y) respectively since t is dependent on z and in (y,z)?

Comment: yes my mistake, i missed that

Comment: Your use of the Cauchy MVT doesn't look right. It should be of the form $(g(b) - g(a))h'(c) = (h(b) - h(a))g'(c)$. But yours is of the form $(g(b) - g(a))h(c) = (h(b) - h(a))g(c)$.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you! missed that

Comment: You have the MVT wrong. Put $g=f'$ into $\frac {f(z)-f(y)}{g(z)-g(y)}=\frac {f'(t)}{g'(t)}$... You "proved" $f'(y)^2=f(y)f''(y)$ for all $y$ for any twice-differentiable $f,$ which is obviously mistaken. A different idea is needed for your Q.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line

$$[f(z)-f(y)]f'(t)=[f'(z)-f'(y)]f(t)$$

which is not true.

Comment: @Bungo You are right.